# Unable to drag marker after search, leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am unable to drag the marker after searching the address and and setting marker on that location.

```
<script>
     
    var lngg, latt,hlat,hlng;
    var marker;
    
            var map = L.map('map').setView([19.8684798, 75.3218784], 10);
           
            map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); 
            marker = L.marker([19.8684798, 75.3218784]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup('My location')
                        .openPopup();
           
           map.locate({setView : true});
   
           marker.dragging.enable();
          
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);
        
            function theLocation(){
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else { 
                    x = document.getElementById('notice');
                    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
                
            } theLocation();
     
    function showPosition(position) {
        latt = position.coords.latitude;
        lngg = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latt + 
            "<br>Longitude: " + lngg;
            marker.setLatLng([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
    }

            function setLocation(){
                position = marker.getLatLng();
                hlat = position.lat;
                hlng = position.lng;
                document.getElementById('lat').value = hlat;
                document.getElementById('lng').value = hlng;
                alert('Location is Set.');
            }

            function onMapClick(e) {

                marker.on("dragend", function(ev) {
                    var chagedPos = ev.target.getLatLng();
                    this.bindPopup("ME at " +chagedPos.toString()).openPopup();
                    loc1 = [chagedPos.lat,chagedPos.lng];
                    hlat = chagedPos.lat;
                    hlng = chagedPos.lng;
                    document.getElementById('lat').value = hlat;
                    document.getElementById('lng').value = hlng;
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Latitude: " + hlat + 
                    "<br>Longitude: " + hlng;
                    console.log(loc1);

            });

            }

            map.on('click', onMapClick);


            var search = new L.Control.Search({
                    url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
                                    jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
                                    propertyName: 'display_name',
                                    propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
                                    marker: L.marker([0,0]),
                                    autoCollapse: true,
                                    autoType: false,
                                    textPlaceholder: ' search the location... ',
                                    minLength: 2
            });

            search.on('search:locationfound',
                    function(e) {

                        marker.setLatLng([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);
                        latt = e.latlng.lat;
                        lngg = e.latlng.lng;
                        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latt + "<br>Longitude: " + lngg;
            });
                       
            
            map.addControl(search);


</script>
```

I also tried to enable again the dragging i.e `marker.dragging.enable();` in ** search.on() ** after setting up the marker location by ** setLatLng() ** but still it's not working.

when I search an address the marker location is setup to that location but then I'm unable to drag that marker.

Answer (score 0):

> when I search an address the marker location is setup to that location but then I'm unable to drag that marker.

There are actually 2 markers at the very same position in this case. One is created by the library (not draggable) and the other one is yours (draggable), and the first marker completely overlays your marker. You just need to disable the first marker by replacing

```
marker: L.marker([0,0]),
```

with

```
marker: false,
```